# I have my 12 word bip39 phrase but not in the right order

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, e-wallet

I have my 12 word phrase, but when i enter it in a wallet, it brings up an empty wallet, so i think i probably wrote it down in the wrong order. What can i do to recover my wallet?

Comment: Which wallet are you using?

Comment: brd wallet and blockchain

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the words are in the right order, since BIP39 includes a checksum word - If they were out of order, it is unlikely that the wallet would have accepted them to even attempt a recovery.

It is more likely that the two wallets you used were using different derivation paths and/or address types.

A seed phrase can lead to many different addresses, such as regular addresses, P2SH-P2PKH addresses, and native segwit P2PKH addresses. Many wallets these days support multiple types of addresses, and you would need to point the wallet to the correct derivation path when restoring a seed.

Moreover, wallets such as electrum default to their own seed semantics, and must be told to use BIP39 explicitly, which can also lead to different addresses being derived.

Your best bet would be to look up the original wallet and see what type of addresses it was deriving, and the derivation path. Then, use another wallet that allows you to restore the same path and address type.

Comment: I have the address, so what can i do?

Comment: A helpful resource to find a wallet's derivation path is https://walletsrecovery.org/ - could be useful to add that into your last paragraph.